# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query 'which was not supplied.'

Tags: sql, json

sale el siguiente error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'La consulta parametrizada '(@solicitante nvarchar(4000),@manager nvarchar(4000),@tipoFecha ' espera el parámetro '@solicitante', que no se proporcionó.'
```

Aquí tengo el código que estoy usando ¿Cuál podría ser  el fallo? ya que no me deja retornar el json, he estado debugeando y se detiene en la excepción

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GuardarPermiso(string Solicitante, string Manager, string TipoFecha, string TipoPago, string Motivo, string HoraEntrada, string HoraSalida, string Justificacion, string TipoJustificacion, string TipoPermiso, string Estatus, string fechaPermiso)
{

            SqlConnection conexion;
            SqlCommand consola;
            Respuesta respuesta;

            conexion = new SqlConnection(configuracion.GetConnectionString("dh"));
            consola = conexion.CreateCommand();
            respuesta = new Respuesta();

            try
            {
                conexion.Open();

                consola.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PERMISOS (Solicitante, Manager, TipoPago, FechaPermiso, Motivo,HoraSalida, " +
                    "HoraEntrada, Justificacion, TipoJustificacion, TipoPermiso, Estatus, FechaRegistro) " +
                "VALUES (@solicitante, @manager, @tipoPago, @fechaPermiso, @motivo, @horaSalida, @horaEntrada," +
                " @justificacion,@tipoJustificacion, @tipoPermiso, @estatus, GETDATE())";

                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solicitante", Solicitante);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manager", Manager);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoFecha", TipoFecha);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoPago", TipoPago);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motivo", Motivo);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@horaSalida", HoraSalida);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@horaEntrada", HoraEntrada);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@justificacion", Justificacion);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoJustificacion", TipoJustificacion);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoPermiso", TipoPermiso);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estatus", Estatus);
                consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaPermiso", fechaPermiso);

                consola.ExecuteNonQuery();

                respuesta.estatus = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                respuesta.estatus = false;
                respuesta.mensaje = $"Error: {e.ToString()}";
            }
            finally
            {
                conexion.Close();
            }

            return Json(respuesta);

        }
    }
}
```

He cambiado el Json para guardar los datos y me salen cada vez diferentes parametros que el controlador necesita, por el momento así es como tengo el json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realiza lo siguiente; crear parámetro por separado y agregarlos; esto es, en lugar de:

```
consola.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);
```

Realizar (por ejemplo para el primer parámetro):

```
var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@solicitante";
parameter.Value = Solicitante;
consola.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

y así cada uno.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Acorde a tu comentario lo que ocurre es que falta indicar cada uno de los parámetros; en el orden que se observa en tu código primero va solicitante, luego manager y así; por tanto lo que debes hacer es para cada variable parámetro crear su variable por separado y agregarla; ejm:

```
var solicitante= command.CreateParameter();
solicitante.ParameterName = "@solicitante";
solicitante.Value = Solicitante;
consola.Parameters.Add(solicitante);

var manager= command.CreateParameter();
manager.ParameterName = "@manager";
manager.Value = Manager;
consola.Parameters.Add(manager);

var tipoFecha= command.CreateParameter();
tipoFecha.ParameterName = "@tipoFecha";
tipoFecha.Value = TipoFecha;
consola.Parameters.Add(tipoFecha);
```

Cada uno debe ser agregado como variable distinta; no hagas lo siguiente:

```
var parametro= command.CreateParameter();
parametro.ParameterName = "@solicitante";
parametro.Value = Solicitante;
consola.Parameters.Add(parametro);

parametro.ParameterName = "@manager";
parametro.Value = Manager;
consola.Parameters.Add(parametro);

parametro.ParameterName = "@tipoFecha";
parametro.Value = TipoFecha;
consola.Parameters.Add(parametro);
```

Fuente en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234971/adding-parameters-to-idbcommand
Acá tambien hay otra forma indicando el tipo de dato: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: Cambie el json y me sale el mismo error pero con diferentes parámetros. Esta vez salió manager y luego tipoFecha.